# Referring to a Dynamically Created JButton

Tags: java, swing

I have a JPanel on which I've dynamically added quite a few JButtons. All of this is working perfectly. Later on in my program execution, I need to refer back to these buttons and pull out the button text. I'm having trouble figuring out how to refer back to them.

When I created each button, I gave it a unique name. Let's say this is the code where I created the button:

```
public void createButton(Container parent, String btnName) {
   JButton btn = new JButton("xyz");
   btn.setName(btnName);
   btn.addActionListner(new ActionListner() {
      //code
   }
   parent.add(btn);
 }
```

In another method, I'm trying to retrieve the label on the button since it may have changed at run time. Do I need to keep an array of these buttons as they are created? Or is there a way that I can refer back to them directly?

This is what I was working on, but it's stupid. Can anyone suggest a correct approach?

```
public String getBtnLabel(String btnName) {
   JButton btn = (JButton) btnName;
   return btn.getText();
}
```

If the answer is that I just need to create the array and then iterate over it, that's fine. Just looking for other options.

Comment: Why are you casting a String to a JButton in your second code block?  Surely this throws an exception!

Comment: your `getBtnLabel` method is completely erroneous . It won't even compile. Apart from that can you tell that where you calling this method?

Comment: Agree to both of you. As I mentioned, this method is stupid, but I was unable to get a better one. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `Map<String, JButton>` so when you create your dynamic buttons you give them some sort of unqiue name:

```
//somewhere at the top of your class
private final Map<String, JButton> myButtonMap = new HashMap<>();

public void createButton(Container parent, String btnName) {
   JButton btn = new JButton("xyz");
   btn.setName(btnName);
   btn.addActionListner(new ActionListner() {
      //code
   }
   parent.add(btn);
   myButtonMap.put(btnName, btn);
 }
```

And then simply get from the map

```
public String getBtnLabel(String btnName) {       
   return myButtonMap.get(btnName).getText();
}
```

This will obviously throw an NPE if the button isn't defined...
Also you will need to delete from your map when you're done with it otherwise you're asking for a memory leak...

Comment: Great idea. Hadn't thought of using a map.

Comment: nice idea. +1 for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use a [`Map< String, JButton >`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

At creation time you put new button into it with [`buttons.put( name, btn )`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put%28K,%20V%29)

In event handler you use [`JButton btn = buttons.get( name )`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you need to keep references to the buttons. An array would be an option, but since arrays are awkward to use, you should prefer a List.

If you have a a reference to the JPanel containing the buttons, you could get them from it. but that is likely to be rather bothersome.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend keeping a list of your buttons or a reference to them in a map, however you could do this:

```
for (Component i : parent.getComponents()) {
    if (i.getName().equals(btnName)) {
         JButton b = (JButton) i;
         // do stuff..
    }
}
```

Using the parent component and iterating over the added components.